# Mongoose query returning nested document with empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema for geoJSON polygon objects structured like this:

```
var polygonZoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location: {
        'type': {
            type: String,
            enum: "Polygon",
            default: "Polygon"
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [[[Number]]]
        }
    },
    zoneType: ObjectId,
    riskiness: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

In my controller I have a function that lists all the polygons:

```
polyZone.find({}).exec(function (err, collections) {
        console.log(collections[0].location.coordinates);
        if (err) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({reason: err.toString()});
        }
        res.send(collections);
    });
```

When inspecting my database through mongo command-line the collection contains:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55fb6e7ab228f7343367116d"),
    "location": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [0, 0],
                [0, 1],
                [1, 1],
                [1, 0],
                [0, 0]
            ]
        ]
    }
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("55fb6e7ab228f7343367116e"),
    "location": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [1, 1],
                [1, 2],
                [2, 2],
                [2, 1],
                [1, 1]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

However when using my controller function the objects being returned have  an empty coordinates array:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55fb6e7ab228f7343367116d",
    "riskiness": 0,
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [],
      "type": "Polygon"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "55fb6e7ab228f7343367116e",
    "riskiness": 0,
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [],
      "type": "Polygon"
    }
  }
]
```

Is this something to do with mongoose? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in mongoose with nested arrays. It has been slotted to be fixed in 4..3 You can read more about it here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1361

Until then I found that by using Model.collection I can use the core mongo driver which does not have any issues with nested arrays

Answer (score 0):

Is it because there are 2 numbers in each coordinate and the schema only specifies one? IOW, should

```
coordinates: {
        type: [[[Number]]]
    }
```

read

```js
coordinates: {
            type: [[[Number, Number]]]
        }
```

Comment: The schema specifies an array of numbers, so the third inner array [Number] would look like something like [1, 2]

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason for my question, which shouldn't really be in the form of an answer I guess. [1,2] is not a number. You sample data shows 2 comma delimited numbers there, but your scheme only specifies one number.

Comment: The schema specifies an array of numbers of size n. [], [1], [1, ... , n] are all valid examples